# How do I undefine yyparse() in bison?

Tags: bison

Bison publically exposes to `yyparse()` function. Is there a way I can stop it from doing that? I want to expose my own wrapper around it whereby I initialise some variables.

Answer (score 1):

Bison will certainly generate the entry point `yyparse`, unless you specify a different global symbol prefix using `%name-prefix` or `%define api.prefix`. (And if you change the prefix, the names of a number of symbols, including `yytext` and `yyleng`, will be changed, so that could be inconvenient.)

But other than the fact that the symbol exists and could therefore be called, it doesn't seem terribly annoying. If you want to wrap the parser with a different function, you can just do that and use the name of that function in your code. The bison generated code itself does not ever call `yyparse`. (It is called by the default `main` function in `liby`, but use of that library is not recommended. If you really want to remove the symbol's definition from the compiled object, you could do so using a linker script, at least on systems which implement linker scripts.

If you really really want to change the name of the `yyparse` function and you are not modifying the global symbol name prefix, then you can insert

```
%define yyparse some_other_name
```

into the prologue code. Ideally, you would place that in a `%code top` block.